# How to detect when intercom is ringing?

Tags: esp8266, relay, buzzer

For my apartment, I need to check when intercom is ringing and call an API in that case. I was thinking about using an AC input / DC output relay, since the buzzer signal is an AC signal. Is there an equivalent pre-built component similar to [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1pcs-ESP8266-ESP-01S-Relay-module-relay-WIFI-intelligent-socket-Add-ESP-01S/32861788818.html)?

Answer (score 2):

As it sounds like you do not own the buzzer (it is part of the appartment), someone may not like you directly connecting to it.

If this is a classic buzzer with an electromagnet, consider using a [Hall Effect Sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect_sensor).  The magnetic field generated by the buzzer may be able to activate the Hall Effect Sensor and inform the Arduino the buzzer has been activated.  [This article](https://maker.pro/arduino/tutorial/how-to-use-a-hall-effect-sensor-with-arduino) talks about Hall Effect sensors and an Arduino.

Image of Arduino and Hall Effect Sensor from linked to article:
[image: Image of Arduino and Hall Effect Sensor from linked to article.]

Further, this is a much safer way connect to a buzzer.  As a classic buzzer can generate very high voltages that can damage processors and other sensitive electronic devices when directly connected.

Comment: Can you please share a wiring diagram?

Comment: There is a diagram from the article linked to in the answer.  I'll add the same image to the answer.

Comment: Most Arduino solutions / answers will use an Arduino Uno.  An ESP8266 is a very complex chip and through the efforts of a few has been added to the list of chips which can be supported using the Arduino Integrated Development Environment (IDE).  The problem with the specific board you have chosen, the eps01 board, is that it brings out very few of the ESP8266's pins to the user.  Further, the ESP8266 is very different from the usual ATmega328P processor used on most Arduino boards. Making it even more difficult to look for examples of exact solutions to your situation.

Comment: Your solution is nice but requires the circuit to be close to the buzzer. What about using a rectifier and a 12V relay to close the arduino 3.3V / input loop?

Comment: The question hinted at using an EP01 device which contains a WiFi radio.  If so, this small "IoT" device could be, as long as power was available, right next to the buzzer.  As it could communicate the state of the buzzer to any other WiFi device wirelessly.  You could use a relay.  But are you sure of the type of signal used by the installed buzzer?  You assumed AC (recommending a rectifier) but it could be DC.  And it may not be 12 volts.